# Is it possible to "talk" with running process?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sockets

i want to create some service that will run as simple process and will give some other application the possibility to send him xml stream.

What i mean is to create simple process ( exe ) with Infinite loop - and any application will be able to send XML ( file / stream ) to this process => and this process will send the xml to some socket.

Is it possible to do it without pipe ?
I want to do something like COM - that can 'catch' instance of working process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure.

you can use Named Pipe classes in c# :

Server :

```
using (var s = new NamedPipeServerStream ("myPipe"))
{
 s.WaitForConnection();
 s.WriteByte (100);
 Console.WriteLine (s.ReadByte());
}
```

client code:

```
using (var s = new NamedPipeClientStream ("myPipe"))
{
 s.Connect();
 Console.WriteLine (s.ReadByte());
 s.WriteByte (200);  
}
```

### edit

you can do it by file. + systemfileWatcher Class

put a file in a folder.

the other process will audit this folder.

and now you can transfer info.

### edit2

you can use memoryMappedFile

and open a view in each process to see the same mempry region - and transfer data.
 I think its the best.

### Process A :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 4000))
            {
                bool mutexCreated;
                Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                    string st = "Hellow";
                    int stringSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(st); //6
                    writer.Write(st);
                    writer.Write(123); //6+4 bytes = 10 bytes
                }
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                Console.WriteLine("Start Process B and press ENTER to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                mutex.WaitOne();
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                    Console.WriteLine("Process  A  says: {0}", reader.ReadString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Process  A says: {0}", reader.ReadInt32());
                    Console.WriteLine("Process  B says: {0}", reader.ReadInt32());
                }
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
```

### Process B writes to its region

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap"))
                {
                    Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("testmapmutex");
                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(11, 0)) // From the 11 byte....
                    {
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                        writer.Write(2);
                    }
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Memory-mapped file does not exist. Run Process A first.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: But my question is if its possible to do it without pipe !

Comment: I want to do something like COM - that can 'catch' instance of working process.

Comment: @Yanshof I dont think you can interact with another process without socket / pipe...

Comment: i know .. but maybe there is some other way that i/we don't know :)

Comment: systemfileWatcher Class is not possible on my case :(

Comment: @aleroot he doesnt want  , network , pipe , socket....I dont know ... maybe by meditation ?

Comment: shared memory could fit well with his requirements, file polling could be really slow ...

Comment: Good idea shared memory ! StackOverflow is strange ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use C# Sockets that listen for connections from the other process and write a custom XML file receiver.

Comment: but i dont want to use network also .. its all run on same machine

Comment: If you want to avoid network connection you can try with shared memory .

Comment: I would use sockets anyway. Just send it to localhost. I do this myself quite alot, network or no network.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course you can use a TCP [socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) connection .If you want to avoid network connection as enlightened in a comment you can use a shared memory approach, for example with [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) .

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is some form of IPC (Inter-process communuication). There's a huge number of possibilities:

1. Regular file. Windows provides location specifically for temp files (%TEMP%)
2. For small data, you could use registry, although in most cases it's not a proper use
3. Memory-mapped file, it's similar to file but in RAM
4. As Royi properly mentioned, NamedPipeStream is a way to go if you decide to give pipes a try
5. You could create a WCF endpoint. It sounds like a drag, but Visual Studio will create you all the scaffolding, so it's not such an issue in the end
6. Window messages could be used if you are developing forms application, and sometimes even if not
7. You mentioned that the data is XML, so this methodology is not for you, but I'll mention it anyway: you could use named kernel objects, such as: mutexes, events, semaphores to pass signals from one program to another.

Comment: Also: Make one of the processes an out-of-process COM server and invoke methods and attach to events on its COM interface. This allows 2 way communication between processes.