# why do I get an access denied exception when accessing a memory mapped file from c# but not from c++

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, memory-mapped-files

I have a WCF service that uses named pipes. Apparently doesn't use the url for the name. It generates a GUID from the url, then stores it in a memory mapped file. So I wrote a C++ app that gets the name of the pipe from the memory mapped file, and that works great.  Now I'm trying to make a c# app that gets the name of the pipe from the memory mapped file. here is the code that I'm using.

```
    private static string GetPipeName(string mappedFileName)
    {
        var mappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(mappedFileName, MemoryMappedFileRights.Read);
        var bytes = new List<byte>();
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream s = mappedFile.CreateViewStream())
        {
            using (var b = new BinaryReader(s))
            {
                bytes = b.ReadBytes((int)b.BaseStream.Length).ToList();
            }

        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

At the first `using` statement I get an UnauthorizedAccessException, that says "Access to the path is denied."

I was able to step through and confirm that the filename is the same that I use in the c++ app and that shows when I use the SysInternals tool Handle.exe

Why would the C# app get an access denied? As far as I can tell both are running as the same user.

Comment: Scott.. can you be more specific with the error.. also could it be Access Error because it appears that the file you are trying to read could be in use by another process which means you are not closing the stream

Comment: looks like you are having a ViewAccessor Issue

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I've updated the question to include more accurate information about the exception. it is just below the code sample.

Comment: so should I be using the CreateViewAccessor method instead of CreateViewStream?

Comment: Checkout this Link and scroll down to the answer.. the individual posted 2 working examples.. I am sure you could add / remove to make it work for your example. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390829/is-it-possible-to-talk-with-running-process

Comment: I used the CreateViewAccessor(Int64, Int64, MemoryMappedFileAccess) method. and it worked. if you want to make an answer I'll accept it, since i wouldn't have thought to try it if it wasn't for you comment.

Comment: I will make that an answer thanks and glad I could help out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the following

```
CreateViewAccessor(Int64, Int64, MemoryMappedFileAccess);
```