# Writeline to already running process

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(args.Length > 1)
    {
        int id;
        if(int.TryParse(args[0], out id))
        {
            try
            {
                var p = Process.GetProcessById(id);
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(args[1]);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't find process with id {id}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't find process with id {args[0]}");
        }
    }
}
```

I got a process by its id.  That worked fine
Then I tried to send something to its stdin.  That threw an InvalidOperationException.  Note: the exception occured when I tried to get the StandardInput, not when I tried to us WriteLine.

I believe I know why I got the exception. The process was not started by my application, so I never had the chance to set RedirectStandardInput to true.

My goal is to be able to use this app to send text to a python interactive console(or another language).  I still want to be able to enter text myself to the python prompt, but I also want to give my app control too.

How do I do this?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390829/is-it-possible-to-talk-with-running-process

Comment: For the ones confused: the `$` prefix is part of C# 6 (string interpolation).

Comment: @ragerory I saw that, but that assumes that you control both processes.  I have no control over a python prompt.  I could write a process starter through which I would start anything I want to send something to, but that is a bit clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you hit the nail on the head. Unless you start the process yourself, you do not own the communication streams - and there isn't really a (reasonable) way around this.

If you run a console application by default, it runs in `cmd` - that's who owns the streams. If you want your application to "host" the process, you'll have to be the one who starts it. You'll just have to learn to call `myHoster myApp` instead of `start myApp` :)

You might also want to consider coding a PowerShell host. This would allow you to quite easily handle an interactive shell, though you'd have to learn to use PowerShell instead of CMD :) It's pretty easy to implement, PowerShell is really quite extensible.