# Single Instance [Windows Must Reopen while working on single Instance....]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If another window is open and software is opened it will open minimized. Please force it to open above already opened instance. Do not allow to open one more instance when clicking on the shortcut icon from desktop.

Single Instance Was Working Fine but The Window cannot be Force to Reopen.

Windows Must Reopen while working on single Instance....

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in help. Your question should contain the code directly, not in an linked image.

Comment: also, you should note, that StackOverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service

Comment: I don't think you can just maximise some other process' window. So you probably have to do something like listen for a windows message in your app and maximise mainwindow if you get it. When you run check if there's a previous instance running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392031/how-to-check-if-another-instance-of-the-application-is-running
send windows message
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142734/send-window-message-to-wpf-application-from-another-wpf-application

Comment: @vasily.sib "а где деньги, Зин"?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean your app runs first , and a window of its has been opened , if re-run the app by shortcut , you want the preview one shows again ?
if so , just monitors the processes ,if there is a new process and it's the same as your app ,then show your window again. and int the app code ,you should use Mutex

Comment: there is an article , you can find answer there http://derpturkey.com/c-cross-process-synchronization/